# mp3 files randomly not playing in Google Earth placemarks

Tags: audio, mp3, google-earth

I have numerous placemarks, each with one or more audio clips embedded (the player and the clips are on my server).

When I click on a placemark, the audio players is there, but the clip does not always play. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not. In the placemarks with more than one clip, some clips play while others do not, and if I close and reopen, different ones will play and others that previously played will not.

As far as I can tell, it is random (does not seem to relate to size of clip, name, or order on server or in placemark).

Any ideas???? I tried turning off antivirus, but no different.